# How to post content with & to a web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem to post a content with & like **"M&A is the trend...."**,the message only stop at M

MVC Web API

```
  [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri] CommentModel param)
        {}

    public class CommentModel
    {       
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Web Api config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

           );
```

Call it from angularJS:

```
 var message = encodeURI($scope.message);   
 var request = $http.post('api/comment/?message=' + message);

....
```

Comment: Look at http encoding

Comment: That is because`&` is a part of url which separates query parameters, you need to encode it first and then send

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, when you perform an HTTP/POST you send the data as an entity as part of request body (not in the URI).

That is, your API controller's method should look as follows:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(CommentModel param)
```

And your HTTP/POST request should both contain a `Content-type: application/json` header and a JSON entity as part of request body (again, not in the URI!!!!).

Finally, if you need to send ampersands as data in your resource URIs or url-form-encoded data, you'll need to encode them since ampersands have specific meaning on this context (they are the key-value pair separator). If you're performing requests from an HTML5 App, you can encode your parameters using[`encodeURIComponent(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aeh9cef7(v=vs.94).aspx) function, and in .NET you can use [`Uri.EscapeDataString`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx)

POST verb is meant to *create* a resource and you send the resource data as an entity (it could be JSON, XML, url-form-encoded, or whatever, but ideally not in the URI as a query string).

Comment: thanks. I used encodeURI($scope.message);  => changed to encodeURIComponent works.

Answer (score 2):

Encode content before sending.

```
M&A is the trend....
```

After encode look like this:

```
M&amp;A is the trend....
```